Winter village display
I really want to start collecting  the Winter village set as I’ve only recently discovered my love for Lego sets!
I would like it to be something I displayed every year. Would it be worth gluing it so I can get it in and out of the loft and so it’s a bit more secure when displayed? I have a 4yo who would be interested in touching it, which I think I would mind a lot less if it were glued. I’m still at the age with my children where they are inquisitive. I want it to be enjoyed and I don’t have a big enough house to have a custom display cabinet so it would just be set up on a table every year.
I’m sorry if this question has been done to death I’ve only just discovered this forum.

Talking about gluing LEGO is a sin!

If it is worth gluing is up to you. No one knows what you prefer.
However, if you glue it are you sure it will hold if someone knocks it off a table? I have disassembled sets which were glued. It made it more robust, but not indestructible.
Are you sure you won’t regret it when the kids are a few years older and you might want to take it apart and rebuild it with them as a Christmas tradition?
Most types of glue will be visible. It makes it far less appealing as a display piece. When Lego glues sets together for display in their stores or similar, they actually don’t glue them. Instead they dissolve a small part of each piece. Sure, you could do this, but the assembly process will be far less fun and more akin to work.
Personally I wouldn’t glue it, but place it on a shelf high up until the kids are older where you can place it on a table.

"Sure, you could do this,", that's only true with some major caveats. The product TLG uses require good ventilation and I believe it's quite hard to actually buy.

Clarification: bricks are glued, not dissolved, for public LEGO models. Yes, the glue dissolves the plastic a tiny bit like any plastic glue does. Also some models are not entirely glued - only some sections of them, which allows them to be disassembled for transportation.
